# How to add extra files to the Drop Location so they're automatically checked into the Drops folder

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfsbuild, azure-devops

Edit: Typical - you write out the question, restart VS and everything is working. :-) I'll leave it here for others in case they get this issue.

We use the online TFS from Microsoft and have created a build definition using the `DefaultTemplate.12.xaml`.

This build is run on the default hosted build agent provided by MS. Once the build completes the output of the build is automatically checked into the Source Control under the `$/Project/Drops` folder, and we can use get latest to get the output.

What I want to do is copy some of the source files to the drop location - such that they too are checked in as part of the build output. Ultimately this will be custom files created by some other part of the build process - but for now simply getting non standard file will be sufficient.

What I've done is edited the TFS Build Template to add a new Copy Directory Activity that copies files from the `SourceDirectory` to the BinariesDirectory, right before the template's standard copy files from `BinariesDirectory` to `DropLocation`.

[image]

[image]

The MS activity is simply a Copy Directory for `BinariesDirectory` to `DropLocation`

I've also tried to do this using InvokeProcess and CMD.EXE /C XCOPY but the custom files are not checked in, only the standard build output.

**NB:**
Just to reiterate - the TFS & Build agent is completely in the MS controlled cloud, and we have no access to changing the drop location to a UNC or other path, and the output is automatically checked into the $/Project/Drops folder in Source Control.

Comment: I would think this would be better done through MSBUILD. Add a target to copy the non-standard files to the output folder, and they should all be included in the drop.

Comment: Would that not also give me warnings when I load my solution? Or are you talking about adding an MS Build Activity to the workflow?

Comment: Why would it give you warnings? I'm not suggesting adding a new `ItemGroup` - that may not be necessary. I see no reason why the additional files would need to appear as part of the project.